# When I Open chrome inspect some element getting overlap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

when open chrome some element getting overlap
like As seen in this picture
I need fix this problem

Comment: Please add enough code for us to see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i add code but show me this 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details 
so i upload the image

Answer (score 0):

Even I have faced the same issue.
What I did is I just opened dev tools in separate window.

Click on the 3 dots icon then you can find dock side option, In dock side select the first option which will pop out the dev tools into new window.

[In this image you can find the dockside option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXyju.png)

[This is how the dev tools window will open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtLee.png)

Now you can view the entire web page as well as dev tools.